# Pairing Time series Data with Batch Data in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have a very large set of time series data in the format of datetime, a, b, c, d, etc. I am reading it from a csv.

I would like to be able to perform summary statistics on this set of time series data for a large number of intervals within that data. This is defined by another imported csv file that has a start and end time stamp in each row. I would like to create another column in the second csv file that has the average/min/max of a, b, c, and d for that given time interval.

For example, a given row in the second table might be (1/12/2023 9:15:35 , 1/12/2023 11:30:32). For that row, I would want the set of statistics for a, b, c, and d between 1/12/2023 9:15:35 and 1/12/2023 11:30:32 . The first table has a data point for every second within the inputted time frame.

I have the below start to this problem but that is really only handling getting the data in correctly. I also calculated intervals between the start and stop times in the second table but I'm not sure how to use these to continue solving the problem. The result is as expected but I'm clueless on how to keep going.

```
library(tidyverse)
apexdata <- read_csv("/Users/xxx/Documents/apex.csv")
ibadata <- read_csv2("/Users/xxx/Documents/iba_Export.txt")

ibadata$time <- dmy_hms(ibadata$time)

apexdata <- data.frame(apexdata, timeperiod=-interval(apexdata$`start`, apexdata$`stop`))
```

At request, here is some example data. Will not be able to reproduce a solution with it though, as the second data set is hundreds of thousands of rows long, so this sample doesn't have enough data to calculate even the first interval. I may decrease the time frequency to cut down on the amount of data but this is what I have for now.

Results of dput suggested below...

```
dput(head(apexdata,20))

structure(list(Unit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), starttime = c("1/14/2024 0:00:03", 
"1/14/2024 0:00:06", "1/14/2024 0:00:10", "1/14/2024 1:32:00", 
"1/14/2024 1:32:00", "1/14/2024 1:32:00", "1/14/2024 1:43:00", 
"1/14/2024 1:48:00", "1/14/2024 1:52:00", "1/14/2024 1:57:00", 
"1/14/2024 2:01:00", "1/14/2024 2:06:00", "1/14/2024 2:10:00", 
"1/14/2024 2:15:00", "1/14/2024 2:19:00", "1/14/2024 2:24:00", 
"1/14/2024 2:28:00", "1/14/2024 2:33:00", "1/14/2024 2:37:00", 
"1/14/2024 2:42:00"), stoptime = c("1/14/2024 0:00:08", "1/14/2024 0:00:12", 
"1/14/2024 0:00:20", "1/14/2024 2:49:00", "1/14/2024 2:55:00", 
"1/14/2024 2:59:00", "1/14/2024 3:04:00", "1/14/2024 3:11:00", 
"1/14/2024 3:15:00", "1/14/2024 3:20:00", "1/14/2024 3:24:00", 
"1/14/2024 3:29:00", "1/14/2024 3:33:00", "1/14/2024 3:38:00", 
"1/14/2024 3:42:00", "1/14/2024 3:47:00", "1/14/2024 3:51:00", 
"1/14/2024 3:56:00", "1/14/2024 4:00:00", "1/14/2024 4:05:00"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

dput(head(ibadata,30))

structure(list(time = structure(c(1705190400, 1705190401, 1705190402, 
1705190403, 1705190404, 1705190405, 1705190406, 1705190407, 1705190408, 
1705190409, 1705190410, 1705190411, 1705190412, 1705190413, 1705190414, 
1705190415, 1705190416, 1705190417, 1705190418, 1705190419, 1705190420, 
1705190421, 1705190422, 1705190423, 1705190424, 1705190425, 1705190426, 
1705190427, 1705190428, 1705190429), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), a = c(21839, 21839, 21839, 2184, 21844, 218453, 2185, 
2185, 218606, 21862, 218674, 21868, 218625, 21862, 218691, 21873, 
21877, 21879, 218831, 21885, 218825, 21879, 218812, 21884, 218867, 
2189, 218902, 21891, 218922, 21897), b = c(2205, 220572, 22062, 
220687, 22073, 220743, 22079, 220816, 2209, 220947, 22108, 22108, 
221126, 22113, 221185, 22119, 221247, 22125, 221373, 22143, 221465, 
22148, 221532, 2216, 221649, 22171, 221738, 22177, 221782, 22183
), c = c(23435, 23435, 23435, 234374, 23447, 23447, 23447, 23447, 
23447, 23447, 234416, 23441, 234465, 23447, 234509, 23453, 23453, 
23453, 234605, 23464, 234615, 23458, 234606, 23464, 234667, 2347, 
234689, 23464, 234662, 23475), d = c(23308, 23308, 233077, 23307, 
23307, 23307, 23307, 23307, 23307, 23307, 233074, 23313, 23313, 
23313, 23313, 23313, 23313, 23313, 23313, 233152, 23319, 233213, 
23325, 23325, 23325, 233251, 23336, 23336, 23337, 233373), e = c(22611, 
22612, 22612, 22612, 226171, 22618, 226138, 22611, 226146, 22617, 
226207, 22623, 22623, 22623, 22623, 22623, 22623, 22623, 22623, 
22623, 22623, 22623, 226239, 22629, 22629, 226341, 22635, 226298, 
22629, 226343), f = c(2278, 22781, 227759, 22775, 22775, 22775, 
227786, 22781, 22781, 22781, 22781, 22781, 22781, 22781, 227816, 
22787, 22787, 22787, 22787, 22787, 22787, 22787, 22787, 227911, 
22792, 227869, 22786, 22786, 22786, 227888), g = c(18867, 18879, 
188788, 18867, 18867, 188632, 18861, 188649, 18867, 188629, 18861, 
18861, 18861, 188629, 18867, 188631, 18855, 18855, 18855, 18855, 
188492, 18849, 18849, 18849, 188533, 18855, 188594, 18861, 18852, 
18849), h = c(1773, 17731, 17736, 177348, 1773, 1773, 1773, 1773, 
1773, 1773, 177192, 17718, 177218, 17724, 17724, 17724, 17724, 
17724, 177211, 17717, 17717, 17717, 17717, 17717, 177159, 17711, 
177121, 17717, 177184, 17724), i = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17), j = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), k = c(104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 
104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 
104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 
104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835, 104835), l = c(196186, 
198153, 198652, 199944, 198159, 197963, 199065, 195913, 196702, 
196708, 196879, 194930, 197112, 197875, 200390, 199174, 196824, 
197605, 197172, 200082, 196605, 196841, 198612, 197962, 197621, 
197014, 197729, 197984, 197198, 196946), m = c(193727, 194671, 
194557, 194623, 195706, 195879, 195672, 195781, 196027, 195989, 
195104, 194442, 194804, 195251, 194984, 195815, 196762, 197694, 
197746, 197808, 197274, 195542, 195577, 194481, 194785, 194834, 
195128, 195177, 196748, 196293), n = c(257690, 258295, 253273, 
263207, 287060, 291882, 293853, 294140, 291764, 292896, 295990, 
288650, 286251, 285801, 286529, 289491, 288419, 283850, 284192, 
286041, 285978, 287937, 286857, 292262, 292865, 280934, 285851, 
283258, 276197, 279833), o = c(261511, 261773, 261767, 259751, 
258722, 259089, 259701, 259877, 25959, 259962, 260708, 262357, 
261321, 260341, 261406, 261216, 260288, 260779, 261716, 262594, 
260852, 259573, 26066, 262512, 261615, 259187, 260353, 260503, 
258265, 257562), p = c(626936, 627071, 632219, 630111, 622312, 
622462, 620979, 620358, 613787, 611566, 620765, 620913, 621307, 
619567, 619049, 618754, 616256, 61397, 616649, 619968, 627465, 
628215, 623739, 627658, 62656, 621474, 623952, 622797, 624502, 
627092), q = c(624144, 6228, 624444, 624776, 623206, 62223, 623977, 
622446, 620586, 622345, 622479, 621403, 621453, 622914, 622879, 
623082, 625422, 62669, 627363, 628626, 62905, 628104, 627644, 
627727, 628124, 627282, 6289, 629243, 628948, 627812), r = c(930035, 
931337, 923942, 924188, 918944, 914098, 906264, 918388, 932029, 
931316, 94113, 949525, 95893, 960039, 957767, 94860, 950414, 
955721, 952335, 945857, 94316, 94025, 936534, 93450, 93505, 936947, 
932007, 938411, 942931, 944234), s = c(913782, 914331, 917071, 
925487, 947097, 956014, 957963, 957825, 959429, 959406, 95762, 
958156, 959762, 960561, 959082, 959443, 959142, 957543, 959185, 
958198, 958171, 959972, 959491, 961616, 95935, 959322, 958079, 
958469, 957539, 956692), t = c(908173, 90750, 911236, 904482, 
893898, 891823, 897302, 902655, 896257, 899124, 901424, 894936, 
898939, 91048, 904791, 900456, 899448, 892944, 898304, 912246, 
913413, 919507, 917222, 918116, 915059, 90899, 903138, 892807, 
889867, 900289), u = c(890908, 890406, 890249, 888641, 884488, 
881455, 881968, 880658, 88288, 884088, 880681, 878949, 880532, 
880853, 881552, 879144, 880398, 882238, 880577, 882038, 882487, 
881405, 881321, 882045, 882263, 888436, 898413, 900874, 900381, 
901677), v = c(113177, 114547, 114681, 115676, 113546, 113653, 
113833, 114229, 113681, 113456, 114761, 114993, 113711, 114364, 
114130, 113361, 113949, 114468, 115709, 114681, 114922, 114943, 
115193, 114952, 115059, 115273, 115799, 115822, 116976, 116562
), w = c(112682, 112565, 112509, 112642, 112719, 112711, 113057, 
11336, 113202, 113054, 113018, 113358, 113719, 113886, 113915, 
113897, 113863, 113981, 114042, 114342, 114658, 114683, 114728, 
114684, 114748, 114561, 114442, 114754, 115002, 115298)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: Hi FactoryData999, welcome to SO. In order to make your question easier to answer, you need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). In your case, one way to do this is to run both `dput(head(ibadata),20)` and `dput(head(apexdata),20)` and copy the results into your question. Alternatively, make some fake data with at least two  start/end time stamps to represent apexdata and some data to represent ibadata with dates that fit into the start/end time stamps of your fake apexdata.

Comment: Depending on the size of your data, one approach could be to `left_join` the second table to all the observations in the first table that match that range, then summarize by line of the 2nd table.

Comment: @LTyrone I think I did what you are saying. I had to doctor the first two sets of start and end times so that some data in the second table fits within that time frame. Does that answer what you are asking for/help?

Comment: @JonSpring That might be a lot of data for each row from the first table but that does make sense to me. Just to be clear, you mean to left join on the first table using that interval right? So if a row from the second table fits into the interval on the right table, join it on to the corresponding row from the first table? Then do some sort of group by/summarize by every row unique unit in the first table?

Comment: @LTyrone OK, I tried that with your original dput head code.  For the real data, yes there will a lot of start and end time stamps overlapping. The intervals will be sequential, but overlapping. So like 1-2:30 PM, 1:15-2:45 PM, 1:30-3:00 PM. But not regular sized intervals, very variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with the `fuzzyjoin` and `dplyr` packages, which you will need to install prior to running this code. I have used mean in this example, but you can review the `dplyr::summarise()` documentation to find out how to generate your other statistics. This example uses your `dput()`s but should scale nicely to your full dataset.

I had to convert your starttime and stoptime columns from character to POSIXct for this to work.

A `fuzzy_left_join()` works by defining which column on the left (time) 'pairs' with the range columns on the right (starttime, stoptime). Then, using `match_fun =` you define how the match should be made e.g. whether to include or exclude the relevant starttime and/or stoptime. In the example below, I have set it so a match is made if time is >= starttime and < stoptime. Change these 'between' parameters if they do not suit:

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

# Converted character dates to POSIXct
apexdata$starttime <- as.POSIXct(apexdata$starttime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
apexdata$stoptime <- as.POSIXct(apexdata$stoptime, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

# Use fuzzy_left_join() to define join fields
result <- ibadata %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(apexdata,
                  by = c("time" = "starttime",
                         "time" = "stoptime"),
                  match_fun = list(`>=`, `<`)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Unit)) %>%
  group_by(Unit) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(a:w), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

# Result (truncated for readability)
data.frame(result[,1:8])
  Unit         a        b        c        d        e       f        g
1    1  49370.20 141279.6  65632.4 23307.00 104030.0 63778.4 86775.20
2    2  80896.67  85044.5  58607.5 58269.17 124390.3 56948.5 75454.67
3    3 100606.50 101764.7 107870.6 65273.00  42981.4 43287.5 52813.00
```

Note that `fuzzy_left_join()` correctly handled the one-to-many relationships. For instance, "2024-01-14 00:00:06" and "2024-01-14 00:00:07" matched to both Unit 1 and 2, while "2024-01-14 00:00:10" and "2024-01-14 00:00:11" matched to both Unit 2 and 3.

Comment: You are the man Tyrone. Unfortunately, little hurdle at the finish line. I took your code, passed in my own variable names, and ran into an error.

Comment: @L Tyrone I posted the error below.  I tried adding {{}} as suggested in this: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/args_data_masking.html   

But the error still thinks 'col' is being passed in to the group by. Any idea how I can fix this?




Error in `dplyr::group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
✖ Column `col` is not found.

Comment: My bad, updated the first post with the code. And the backtrace thing that the studio recommends.

Comment: Thats why I'm so confused. I have two versions of this code(one with fake data and variable names and one with real variable names and data) but they both return the same error. I only see one line in the code that has "group_by()" and in neither case is "col" inside the parentheses. It is either "Unit" or "heatSC." I don't know why the interpreter thinks "col" is there. 

Could i be having an issue like this: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html   ?

Comment: I will try it with the dput next. Thank you. I was using the actual data.

Comment: Here is the new thread that is created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77869403/r-group-by-column-col-not-found

Hopefully formatting / format is better than this one...

Comment: @FactoryData999 - I am so sorry, I see jpsmith found the error over at your other question. I should have picked this up and didn't. Humblest apologies, I was sure I tried this but I must have only checked the "time" column and not the range columns.

Comment: No need to apologize Tyrone. You've already been so helpful. You have no idea how helpful this piece of code will be to me. All that error is ridiculous. These are the reasons I shouldn't quit my day job for programming!

Comment: @L Tyrone sorry to keep bothering but I subbed in a larger dataset (the whole timeframe im interested in but i did cut it down to minute by minute data instead of second by second) and got an error as follows: 

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 102.3 Gb

So... Is my best bet to subset my datasets and perform it on smaller portions of the data? Apexdata is now 78592 observations of 17 variables and ibadata is 175200 observations of 9 variables (already took out a few columns).  Is taking out rows or columns from the datasets going to be more effective in reducing memory?

Comment: Actually this is probably a new question at this point huh?

Comment: @FactoryData999 - yes, that's better asked as a new question. I can think of a few strategies to manage your data so tag me in a comment on your new question so I get a notification and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Ticked but I am not able to updvote : ( . I think I am going to take a stab with data.table... Google searches are telling me its more memory efficient/faster so I will try that and tag you on a new post if it goes poorly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77876111/rewrite-time-interval-fuzzy-join-to-be-less-memory-intensive  This is the next thread...